# В функции вместо того что бы обрабатывать глобальную переменную, создаётся локальная

Tags: python, функции, global-variables

К примеру:

```
can_do = True
def func_1():
    while can_do:
        do_something()

def func_2():
    can_do = False
```

И вместо того, что бы обработать функцию `can_do`, программа создает локальную переменную.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите **изменять** глобальную переменную, то нужно объявлять её глобальной:

```
def func_2():
    global can_do
    can_do = False
```

А вот **читать** глобальную переменную можно и без объявления её глобальной, как вы и делаете в первой функции. Так вот хитро сделано в питоне.

Comment: так, как у ТС в func_1, работать не будет, 'can_do' referenced before assignment же ж

Comment: @Jack_oS будет будет

Comment: @Эникейщик как как? can_do ведь в ней - локальная ...

Comment: @Jack_oS запустите и проверьте

Comment: @Jack_oS Ещё раз. Когда вы читаете переменную, Питон автоматически ищет её во всех областях видимости, начиная с локальной и кончая глобальной. А вот когда вы меняете переменную, то если нет декларации, что переменная глобальная, Питон по дефолту считает, что переменная локальная. Видимо, так сделано для того, чтобы не загромождать программу декларациями `global`, если вы хотите только читать какие-то настройки из глобальной видимости и т.п. Но в результате вот все путаются чо как.

Comment: При этом если в одной функции переменная **и читается и присваивается**, тогда Питон не может разорваться и считает в обоих случаях её локальной и вот тут то и будет ошибка `referenced before assignment`, если не объявить переменную как `global` и попытаться её прочитать до присваивания.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо!